# Label format in RefTex

Tags: emacs

I am trying to configure RefTeX/AUCTeX so that the smart label-creation, invoked with `C-c (` has the following sets of behaviors:

- for \section-type labels, i.e., for \section, \subsection, etc. generate a label of the form: `\label{sec:[[derived-from-section-name]]}` where what follows the colon is derived from the section name.
- for \items in an enumerate environment, generate a label of the form: `\label{item:[[number]]}`, where the number is automatically incremented from what has gone before. i.e., the first enumerate item I generate a label for gets `\label{item:1}`, the next one `\label{item:2}`, and so on.

This was standard behavior of my reftex implementation when I was using aquamacs, but I haven't been able to duplicate this in standard emacs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX` to `t` like I do in my [config](https://github.com/ska2342/ska-init-files/blob/master/dot.emacs.d/init.el#L782).

Using the config linked to above the behavior is exactly how you described it. I'm on Linux, Emacs version 25.2.2, AUCTeX version 12.1.2, RefTeX version 25.2.2.